# Conditionally filter on SQL query based on the field value

Tags: apex, soql

I want to conditionally filter a SQL query based on the field value of a picklist. How do I do this? If the picklist field value is 'Any Type' then I want to NOT filter the query.

```
if (picklistValue == 'Any Type') //dont filter     

SELECT Object__c.Name
FROM Object__c
WHERE Object__c.Type__c = :picklistValue
```

Comment: This was supposed to say SOQL. cosmoonot made edits and I'm not on here much so i can't change it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In these scenario's you need to build `SOQL` dynamically based on your conditions. In your case dynamic `SOQL` could be something like this:

```
List<Object__c > objList = new List<Object__c>();
String query = 'SELECT Object__c.Name FROM Object__c ';

if(picklistValue == 'Any Type') {// don't filter
    // your code..
} else {
    // apply filter
    query = query + ' WHERE Object__c.Type__c = \'' + picklistValue + '\';

}

objList = Database.query(query);
```

You can refer [dynamic SOQL documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_dynamic_soql.htm) for more details.